# Will this usage of event lead to memory leak in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, memory-leaks

I'm wondering if this usage of events will cause memory leaks in Silverlight?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var test = new ChildWindow();
    EventHandler closedEvent = null;
    closedEvent =
        (s, args) =>
        {
            test.Closed -= closedEvent;
            if (test.DialogResult == true)
            {
                // something
            }
        };
    test.Closed += closedEvent;
    test.Show();
}
```

I have dozen sample usage of Closed event which are left wired and leaky. Just wondered if this sample would eliminate the memory leak?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t see any reason for memory leak. On every button click u allocate new ChildWindow object, which will be garbaged after method ended, coz you not store reference.
Labda (its object too) will be garbaged after the ChildWindow object.

Comment: Yeah it seems so. But the compiler generates a class for each lambda expression, which holds references to both the ChildWindow object and the event object. This class makes things a little complicated.
I think a tool(which i don't have) will help us here to be sure.